How to calculate centralization of a social network in iGraph or Gephi using a list of centrality values instead of a graph?
I'm analyzing social network data using a couple different tools. I originally fed the data through Gephi, which gives me an xml output that I'm cleaning in R before importing it in Tableau. I'd like to calculate the (Freeman's) centralization values for degree, betweenness, and closeness in one of these three programs.
I was able to calculate the node-level degree, betweenness, and closeness centrality in Gephi, but from what I've researched, Gephi doesn't have a way to calculate the network-level centralization values (though I would LOVE to be wrong about this!), so I'm trying to do so in R. Because I used Gephi to generate my graph and I'm only using R for cleaning up the xml output, I don't have a graph object generated in R, so when I go to use something like centr_betw, I get a "wrong object type" error.
Is there a simple way to use iGraph (or any other package in R) to calculate the centralization values based on a vector object or a column in a dataframe? Or, is there a way to calculate these values from Gephi?
Thank you!
Update I've tried the following:
centralize(q3_nodes_clean$betweenesscentrality)

gave me the output of "Inf" .
centr_betw(q3_nodes_clean$betweenesscentrality,directed=FALSE)

yielded the error "Error in ensure_igraph(): ! Must provide a graph object (provided wrong object type).". And
centr_betw_tmax(q3_nodes_clean$betweenesscentrality) 

yielded the same graph object error.

Did you read the documentation of igraph::centralize()?

I did! And it looks like the arguments of centralize() can (maybe?) accept a vector, but I can't specify which type of centrality I'd like to do (though I'm not sure how much this matters), and it looks like all of the accompanying tmax functions in iGraph need a graph object to calculate the theoretical max, so I think I'm back where I started (but I'm happy to be proven wrong!)

To compute centralization, you only need the centrality scores. It doesn't matter what kind of centralities they are. If you want to normalize centralization using the theoretical maximum centralization value, then of course you need to figure out what this maximum is. If igraph has a corresponding centr_xxx_tmax function, you can use that, but first check that it really is for the very same kind of centralization you are working with. If not, it's up to you to derive this maximum value.

"and it looks like all of the accompanying tmax functions in iGraph need a graph" This is not the case. You can omit the graph and specify all other parameters (typically, number of vertices and directedness). The graph parameter is just for convenience: then all other parameters are taken from the graph automatically.

How do I run those functions without a graph object? I'm looking at betweenness centrality, and just tried to run a few functions, and it gave me errors. centralize(q3_nodes_clean$betweenesscentrality) gave me the output of "Inf" . centr_betw(q3_nodes_clean$betweenesscentrality,directed=FALSE) yielded the error  "Error in ensure_igraph():
! Must provide a graph object (provided wrong object type).". And centr_betw_tmax(q3_nodes_clean$betweenesscentrality) yielded the same graph object error.

With centralize you need to provide theoretical.max, which you didn't. You can obtain it from centr_betw_tmax, as I described above.

That still wasn't working either. I ended up just converting my edge files into a graph object and am trying that approach (which is resulting in additional errors, but I've created a separate question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79046920/why-are-my-igraph-centralization-calculations-resulting-in-0-nan)

What I described does work. Perhaps you are doing something else without realizing it. If you provide a minimal reproducible example, we can correct what you are doing.
